# Breezejs not mapping odata relations because of missing inverse property

Tags: javascript, c#, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I am tring to fetch a collection of userentities from my webapi that has a many to many relation with a domainentity. I am using breezejs to fetch these entities and map them to backbone models.

ApiUserEntity:

```cs
public class ApiUserEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public ApiUserRole? Role { get; set; }
    public ApiPermission? Permission { get; set; }

   // Relations
   public virtual IList<DomainEntity> Domains { get; set; } 
}
```

DomainEntity:

```cs
public class DomainEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ApiUserEntity> ApiUsers { get; set; }
}
```

My webapiconfig:

```cs
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.EntitySet<ApiUserEntity>("ApiUsers");
builder.EntitySet<DomainEntity>("Domains");

config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "odata",
    routePrefix: "odata",
    model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
    batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
    );
```

I then have a apiusers controller with the following fetch method:

```cs
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<ApiUserEntity> Get()
{
    return this._apiUserService.GetUsers();
}
```

Using breezejs i execute the following query:

```js
new breeze.EntityQuery().from("ApiUsers").expand("domains")
```

Which sends the following url to my webapi:

```json
GET /odata/ApiUsers?$expand=Domains HTTP/1.1
```

When i inspect the results of this url with fiddler i see the following json:

```
{
    "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:61084/odata/$metadata#ApiUsers", "value":[
        {
            "odata.type": "Base.DAL.Entities.ApiUserEntity", "odata.id": "http://localhost:61084/odata/ApiUsers(1)", "Domains@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "http://localhost:61084/odata/ApiUsers(1)/Domains", "Domains": [
                {
                    "odata.type": "Base.DAL.Entities.DomainEntity", "odata.id": "http://localhost:61084/odata/Domains(1)", "ApiUsers@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "http://localhost:61084/odata/Domains(1)/ApiUsers", "Modules@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "http://localhost:61084/odata/Domains(1)/Modules", "Name": "testdomain", "Url": "http://www.bla.com", "Active": true, "ConnectionString": "string", "Id": 1, "CreatedAt@odata.type": "Edm.DateTime", "CreatedAt": "2015-08-22T18:43:55"
                }
            ], "Username": "test", "Password": "xqCpJRCFNpwWwF0COhak2qJjg1omoxZ7og==", "Email": "test@test.nl", "Salt": "eOr5QncrLczjHbYGDxu+KsdW/1sKRlVTMg==", "Role": null, "Permission": null, "Id": 1, "CreatedAt@odata.type": "Edm.DateTime", "CreatedAt": "1899-12-31T23:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see it includes the user "test" along with his domain "testdomain".
But breezejs does not map these to my entities. i started debugging and found that it returns because it does not see an inverse property on the result in the mergeRelatedEntities function (line 15480 in breeze.debug.js)

```js
function mergeRelatedEntities(mc, navigationProperty, targetEntity, rawEntity) {
    var relatedEntities = mergeRelatedEntitiesCore(mc, rawEntity, navigationProperty);
    if (relatedEntities == null) return;

    var inverseProperty = navigationProperty.inverse;
    if (!inverseProperty) return;
```

In the relatedentities object is all of the domain info:

```json
changing: false
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
active: true
apiUsers: Array[0]
connectionString: "string"
createdAt: Sat Aug 22 2015 20:43:55 GMT+ 0200(West - Europa(zomertijd))
id: 1
modules: Array[0]
name: "testdomain"
url: "http://www.bla.com"
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c37"
entityAspect: EntityAspect
```

but it does not continue mapping because the inverse property on the navigation property is null:

```json
associationName: "Base_DAL_Entities_ApiUserEntity_Domains_Base_DAL_Entities_DomainEntity_DomainsPartner"
entityType: EntityType
entityTypeName: "DomainEntity:#Base.DAL.Entities"
foreignKeyNames: Array[0]
foreignKeyNamesOnServer: Array[0]
invForeignKeyNames: Array[0]
invForeignKeyNamesOnServer: Array[0]
inverse: null
isScalar: false
name: "domains"
nameOnServer: "Domains"
parentType: EntityType
validators: Array[0]
```

I am using the latest breezejs-client (1.5.4) from bower along with backbone backing store and entity framework 6.0 on the backend.

Comment: Did you map the relating table (UserDomain or whatever) as an entity?

Comment: Do you mean in the webapi? I added the domain entity to the edm model by using builder.EntitySet<DomainEntity>("Domains");